# Where do i declare JS dependencies if the js is in a php if statement

Tags: javascript, php, if-statement, popup

Below is a sample of a popup alert id like to use,im not certain where i define the dependencies of the script, is it in head? what do i do if there is no html on the page for me to have a head section  ?

```
if ($rowcount== 0)
{
echo ("<script>
    $(function(){
        $.jAlert({
            'title': 'nada',
            'content': 'nada',
            'closeOnEsc': false,
            'closeOnClick': false
        });
        $.jAlert({
            'title': 'click',
            'content': 'click',
            'closeOnClick': true
        });
        $.jAlert({
            'title': 'esc',
            'content': 'esc',
            'closeBtn': false,
            'closeOnEsc': true
        });
        errorAlert('test alert');
        successAlert('Hi!', 'You did it!');
        alert('test alert');
    });


 $connection->close();

 exit;

 }
```

Comment: Your JS string isn't even closed ! It will pop some errors !

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're talking about the jQuery library.  You have to declare your dependencies (in this case the jQuery library) BEFORE your script.  As long as it's always BEFORE your script whether it's at the end of the document right before the `<body>` tag or in your `<head>` tag.  Otherwise, technically, the scripts can go anywhere within the `<body>` tag, so just output what you've got for now together.

I would change your code to this:

```
if ($rowcount== 0)
{
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jquery-ui-jalert.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $.jAlert({
            'title': 'nada',
            'content': 'nada',
            'closeOnEsc': false,
            'closeOnClick': false
        });
        $.jAlert({
            'title': 'click',
            'content': 'click',
            'closeOnClick': true
        });
        $.jAlert({
            'title': 'esc',
            'content': 'esc',
            'closeBtn': false,
            'closeOnEsc': true
        });
        errorAlert('test alert');
        successAlert('Hi!', 'You did it!');
        alert('test alert');
    });
</script>
<?php 
     $connection->close();
     exit;
}
```

==UPDATE==

The `<?php` and `?>` you see are essentially, in this use case, the same thing as echo.  Doing this: `echo "Hi";` is the same as `?>Hi<?php`

Comment: ok so your putting the script outside of the php code ?

Comment: thats not working for me

Comment: jAlert requires jquery, jquery-ui and jquery-ui-jalert. See the demo here: http://dochoffiday.com/_demo/jquery-ui-jalert/

Comment: @Ultimater - Good point!  Updated!

Comment: @user5420896 - well preferably yes!  It's far cleaner from an IDE and syntax standpoint and quite frankly that's one of the perks of php, you can output raw html within the code block.  You can alternatively use ob_start() and ob_get_clean() if you needed the output to be buffered to a variable.